# Renaming Bluetooth device not working

Tags: macos, bluetooth, system-settings

I run 10.12.6 and I'm wondering how I can rename a Bluetooth device. The function `Bluetooth Preferences > Right click > Rename` seems to be a no-op, see below gif.

[image]

Is there a configuration file that I can edit manually with a text editor? I don't mind getting my hands dirty in `.plist` files and stuff.

Comment: Have you tried doing this while the device was connected? Might have a different result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot rename bluetooth device on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293286/cannot-rename-bluetooth-device-on-my-mac)

Comment: I don't have the offending system anymore to test.

Comment: None of the solutions below worked for me but https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405292/13113 did!

Answer (score 2):

Of course **there is a .plist file to (backup and) delete**.

1. First of all close your Mac's Bluetooth
2. Open *Finder*
3. From toolbar select -> Go -> Go To Folder
4. Copy paste this path `/Library/Preferences`
5. Locate the file `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` and rename it to
   `com.apple.BluetoothOLD.plist`
6. Then do the step 3 again and
7. Copy paste this address `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost`
8. Locate a file that starts with `com.apple.Bluetooth...` and rename
   it.
9. Restart your Mac
10. Re-enable your Bluetooth and try again

Comment: Unfortunately, this deletes all paired devices and renaming does not work.

Comment: @oarfish hmm.. Did you have any luck with the other solution?

Comment: @oarfish You can also rename the Display Name of your device manually from the file above. 
First of all copy the .plist file to your desktop. 
The path to find the value of display name from your bluetooth device inside the .plist file is `DeviceCache/[your device mac address]/displayName`. Move the .plist file again to the previous location, turn off and turn on again mac's bluetooth and you should have your Bluetooth device renamed.

Comment: Which file are you referring to? The one in `/Library/Preferences` contains only one occurrence of `DeviceCache`, unrelated to the device in question, the other file does not contain the key at all.
It should be noted that in order to edit the files, one must `sudo plutil -convert xml1` them to make them editable in plaintext, or use XCode.

Comment: @oarfish Is pretty weird the thing that you can't find your device cache dictionary in the file under `/Library/Preferences`. And I suppose this is the reason you can't rename it. Close your mac's bluetooth. Try to make a new entry in `DeviceCache` dictionary with key name your bluetooth's mac address and type `Dictionary`. Inside this dictionary create a new key with name `displayName` type `String` and Value, the name you want. Open your bluetooth again. Did you have any luck now?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bluetooth Debug Menu:

**This is your solution of last resort, if you use this method your Mac will delete all of your Bluetooth devices and you will need to reconfigure all of them again.**

To use this solution you need to have the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar (and as I saw from your screenshot you have it).

1. Press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click the Bluetooth icon.
2. From debug option, choose first *Remove all devices* and then *Reset the Bluetooth module*
3. As always "restart your mac" and try again to pair and rename your Bluetooth device

More information can be found [here](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-bluetooth-menu-reset-devices).